# Java Android studio Application - How to rename correctly photos after taking them with the camera?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've a little problem. There are 2 days that I am trying to solve it without success.

I am trying to create an app that name every photo taken by a predefined name (ex : "coucou.jpg" instead of "IMG_20191119_201907.jpg").

So I've applyed some tutorials on the internet (https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView  -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8890GpBwn9w (in french))

And it works !... Almost !

The photo are well created in the folder "Pictures".
But the problem that I have is the following : Created files don't receive the name that I gave to them. They are named 1574245595878.jpg - 1574245714222.jpg - 1574358229963.jpg - etc.

And I don't know where I'm wrong... I give you my code, normally, they should be called "coucou.jpg")

Can someone help me to give them the good name (or at least to rename them after creation in the same code) please ? It would be wonderful !

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RETOUR_PRENDRE_PHOTO = 1;
    private Button btnPrendrePhoto;
    private ImageView imgAffichePhoto;
    private String photoPath = null;
    private Bitmap image;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initActivity();
    }

    private void initActivity(){
        btnPrendrePhoto = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPrendrePhoto);
        imgAffichePhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgAffichePhoto);
        btnPrendrePhoto.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prendreUnePhoto();
            }
        });
    }

    private void prendreUnePhoto(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
            File photoDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            try {
                File photofile = File.createTempFile("coucou",".jpg",photoDir);
                photoPath = photofile.getAbsolutePath();
                Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".fileprovider", photofile);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RETOUR_PRENDRE_PHOTO);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==RETOUR_PRENDRE_PHOTO && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
            imgAffichePhoto.setImageBitmap(image);
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), image, "coucou.jpg", "description");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You create every time two files. One by the camera app using your file provider and another by storing the first one by the media store. Why do wanna have two files? Remove the MediaStore call that saves the bitmap.

Comment: You can have only one file with the name coucou.jpg. if you take another picture the file will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `createTempFile()` it will append `timestampInMillis` to end of created `File`, that's the numbers you are looking at in your case, so try creating a normal File

replace

```
File photofile = File.createTempFile("coucou",".jpg",photoDir);
```

with

```
File image = new File(photoDir, "coucou.jpg");
```

Comment: No. This is not true.